# Georgian on arrival for Canadian visa holders

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, georgia-country

I am planning to travel to Canada from 18th June to 5th July. I got to know that when you have Canadian visa, you can go to Georgia visa free. I will be leaving Canada on 28th June and I would like to visit Georgia. Although my visa is valid till 5th July, its single entry visa.

Will I be able to enter Georgia with used Canadian visa?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=956&lang=Eng the visa has to be valid

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a used Canadian visa is accepted for entry to Georgia.

Whether it has to be valid (ie unexpired) or can be expired, I don't know for sure, but at any rate there's no restriction on using a used visa.